# Custom Middleware Not working when using Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

I am using Dynamic database for my laravel API Project. I am doing that with a middleware. When I use `auth:sanctum` in api rout middleware not working. But normally its working fine.

Route> api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'database'], function() {
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', function () {
            return "conncted sucessfully to database ".\DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        });
    });
});
```

Middleware > Database.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\SoftClient;

class Database
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = app('router')->getRoutes()->match($request);
        $prefix = $route->action['name'];

        $s_client = SoftClient::where('url', $prefix)->first();
        \Config::set('database.connections.multidomain.host', $s_client->db_host );
        \Config::set('database.connections.multidomain.database', $s_client->db_name );
        \Config::set('database.connections.multidomain.username', $s_client->db_username );
        \Config::set('database.connections.multidomain.password', $s_client->db_password );

        \DB::reconnect('multidomain');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`'database' => \App\Http\Middleware\Database::class,`

I add this to Karnel.php

When I send request to dashboard I got bellow error. If I not use `auth:sanctum` It's working fine.

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score -1):

auth sanctum is used to authenticate user. Maybe you are directly accessing the routes with authenticating user.

Answer (score -1):

when you check the routes with "php artisan route:list", do you see the middleware you configured with the route?
I had a similar problem, where route:list pointed me to the fact that the middleware I defined with the group wasn't actually used, and in the end I dropped the "group" and just defined the routes individually. A bit cumbersome but it worked.

Comment: Consider adding context to your answer to help make it more "self-contained."  Sometimes answers are linked in such a way that reader won't necessarily see the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

if your goal is to use laravel sanctum for dynamic database connection then i use this method and it works

step 1 : copy this file Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful to our middlewear and then modify duplicate this file like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming requests.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  callable  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        $this->changeDatabaseConnection($request);
        $this->configureSecureCookieSessions();

        return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(static::fromFrontend($request) ? [
            function ($request, $next) {
                $request->attributes->set('sanctum', true);

                return $next($request);
            },
            config('sanctum.middleware.encrypt_cookies', \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class),
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            config('sanctum.middleware.verify_csrf_token', \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class),
        ] : [])->then(function ($request) use ($next) {
            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    protected function changeDatabaseConnection($request)
    {
        $encodeCc   = $request->input('cc');
        $cc         = json_decode(base64_decode($encodeCc));

        if ((!empty($cc) && $cc != 'axiasolusi')) {
            $compCode = $cc;

            if (App::environment() === 'local') {
                $compCode = 'ess-' . $compCode;
            }
        } else {
            $compCode = env('DB_DATABASE');
        }

        Config::set('database.connections.' . env("DB_CONNECTION") . '.database', $compCode);
    }

    /**
     * Configure secure cookie sessions.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureSecureCookieSessions()
    {
        config([
            'session.http_only' => true,
            'session.same_site' => 'lax',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given request is from the first-party application frontend.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function fromFrontend($request)
    {
        $domain = $request->headers->get('referer') ?: $request->headers->get('origin');

        if (is_null($domain)) {
            return false;
        }

        $domain = Str::replaceFirst('https://', '', $domain);
        $domain = Str::replaceFirst('http://', '', $domain);
        $domain = Str::endsWith($domain, '/') ? $domain : "{$domain}/";

        $stateful = array_filter(config('sanctum.stateful', []));

        return Str::is(Collection::make($stateful)->map(function ($uri) {
            return trim($uri) . '/*';
        })->all(), $domain);
    }
}
```

step 2 : change karnel like this

```
'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, // original
            \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

and last step : change route api

```
Route::middleware('change.database')->group(function () {

                Route::post('/verify-company-code', 'Api\Web\Auth@verifyCompanyCode');
                Route::post('/verify-user-account', 'Api\Web\Auth@verifyUserAccount');
                Route::post('/verify-user-pin', 'Api\Web\Auth@verifyUserPin');
                Route::post('/forgot-password', 'Api\Web\Auth@forgotPassword');
                Route::post('/reset-password', 'Api\Web\Auth@resetPassword');
            });

            Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {

                Route::post('logout', [Auth::class, 'logout']);
                Route::post('logout-all', 'Api\Web\Auth@logoutAll');
            });
        });
```

Comment: note if you don't want to change the database name but just want to add a new connection, then you have to set a default connection in every method that accesses the database

Comment: Don't just say "change [kernel] like this." Identify the changes you made. Same with `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php`, there's no indication of what you've changed from the original. You shouldn't even be copying and pasting from the original, just extend the class and override the few functions you need changed.

Comment: oke thanks sir :)